# What is the default location for dll on a linux system?

Tags: linux

After researshes, I know dll files can be used under linux system. I'm able to use them when I have a specific path to give.

Is there a path where to put them which linux look up automatically, equivalent to

```
C:\Windows\System32 ?
```

Some sites recommended `usr/local/lib`, but linux doesn't look there automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file `/etc/ld.so.conf` contains the list of directories the dynamic linker will attempt to automatically load libraries from. This file often includes other configuration files under the `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` directory.

After modifying this file you will need to update the cache using by running `ldconfig` as root.

Some distro's have other tools to manage this file for you. If the ld.so.conf file contains a comment claiming it is auto generated, you should refer to your distro's documentation on how to make changes.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The file you said already contain usr/local/lib. However even with the dll being there, it doesn't seems to be loaded, because as soon as I use something needing the dll, it says dll cannot be found. dll is nunit.frameworkd.dll

Comment: Shared libraries on Linux normally have the .so extension. Are you sure this is a Linux shared library and not a Windows one? They aren't compatible. Try running `file nunit.frameworkd.dll` to determine the type of file. Additionally you can run `ldd <executable name>` and you may see the name of the library that is missing (if it is always loaded at startup)

Comment: nunit.framework.dll: PE32 executable (DLL) (console) Intel 80386 Mono/.Net assembly, for MS Windows

Comment: so I see, it's windows so it doesn't load it? Because I don't run it directly, this is the mono compiler which uses it. But from what I understand since it's a Windows dll it's not gonna be loaded automatically?

Comment: Ah, in this case mono is responsible for loading the .NET assembly. I wrongly assumed it was a shared library. Try adding `MONO_PATH=/usr/local/lib` before the name of your command

Comment: Thanks again for the help. I'm writing this : MONO_PATH=/usr/local/lib

gmcs -t:library -r:nunit.framework.dll but seems nunit.framework.dll stil cannot be found?

Comment: however it's ok I made it work in a different way. thanks again for all the help - really appreciated